# how to extract last two digits from a number using bitwise operator and also remove them from number in short work of %100 and /100 but in bitwise

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have to create an array using uint8_t type from uint64_t type given value in big endian format .
I am trying to extract last two digits again and again , and fix in array but use of modulo and division operator forbidden only bitwise operator can be used.

Comment: This is not easy.  If this is really the assignment, then you are going to have to implement long division in terms of the bitwise operators.  It is theoretically possible, as they are [functionally complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness), but the resulting code will be very long.  This is too big a question for a single SO post.  I would suggest first clarifying the actual requirements of your assignment.

Comment: Function Name
ft_32bit2string


Prototype
uint8_t *ft_32bit2string(uint32_t)


Description
This function takes a 32 bit input and returns a bit string (or an array of type uint8_t) in Big Endian format


Libc functions
malloc(3)

Comment: please answer @nate-eldredge

Comment: I still don't really understand the question.  But from the comment you posted, it doesn't sound to me like the function is supposed to deal with decimal digits at all.  It's not quite clear what "bit string" means, whether it should be one bit per byte or 8 bits.  I think you should go back to whoever assigned this task and ask them for a more precise specification of what the function should do.

Comment: It seems from your comment that the function should return something like `f(0) ==> "00000000000000000000000000000000"`  `f(1) ==> "00000000000000000000000000000001"`  `f(2) ==> "00000000000000000000000000000010"`  `f(3) ==> "00000000000000000000000000000011"` that's what I would call a bit string. IOW, a string made of 32 characters '0' or '1' - one for each bit of the original input. That's not like %100 and /100 but rather %2 and /2, which is much much easier with bit operations.

Comment: @aka.nice it is the problem we have to divide those 32 bit in integral of 8 bit and put those 8-8 bits in an array in big endian form also only with the help of bit wise operations